# Подключиться к HTML чату через python?

Tags: python, chat, client

Реально ли залогиниться к HTML чату и отправлять сообщения используя питон?
например вот такой чат https://www.chatlist.su/main/
Хочу написать скрипт отправляющий время от времени , от моего имени сообщения. Накиньте вариантов.

Comment: можно, конечно...

Comment: Как это осуществить?

Comment: модуль requests с его Session() поможет... залогинитесь и будете время от времени отправлять сообщения от своего имени...

Comment: залогинится получилось, как произвести ввод сообщения в чат ?

Comment: отправляйте post на https://www.chatlist.su/send.php?room=main

Comment: разобрались с отправкой в чат?